# On the Fly GZIP to FTP server

Tags: android, ftp, gzip

I want to take a file that is on the sdcard and GZip it on the fly as I FTP it.  I don't want to create an interrum file save it as gzip then delete both files as someone suggested.  There has got to be a way to do this in code on the fly.  Issue I have is some of these files are 250M. So my basic code looks like this:

```
FTPClient con;
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(files[i]);
boolean result = con.storeFile(files[i].getName(), in);
```

If I could insert that would be great but this fails for obvious reasons:

```
GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(in);
con.storeFile(files[i].getName(), gzip);
```

I get a Magic number error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/).  It supports in-memory gzip compression.  You can simply compile it into your code.

Comment: `deflateInit2()`, `deflate()`, `deflateEnd()` is a piecewise compression engine that allows you to feed in small bits at a time and take small bits out.  See http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html for an example.  `deflateInit2()` instead of `deflateInit()` allows you to select the gzip format.

Comment: So I would have to compile this NDK and JNI it in Android?  DO I have to worry about array memory allocation?  Seems I remember somewhere that allowing NDK to create arrays has some negative effects on memory space.

Comment: NDK provides an interface to zlib.  zlib does not use very much heap (less than 1MB), so is not a problem for Android devices that typically have a 16MB heap.

Comment: Too much work to do on the phone for the one time I have to use it in line.  But nice suggestion...will have to try later when I have more time or you actually write the JNI for it.